# scripting with powershell..creating subforders with no spaces btn names

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that creates sub Folders and the names of all the subfolders created should not have spaces. For example for a new folder called `MY SPACE`, I want the script to create it with a name like `MY_SPACE` instead.

How can i make this happen?

Comment: So you want to edit name of all existing folders,rather than adding new ones, right?

Comment: yeah that was the idea

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
$SubDirName = 'MY SPACE'
mkdir $SubDirName.replace(' ', '_')
```